# HTML5 svg image tag - opacity

Tags: svg, opacity

I sincerely hope you can help me out here.
I'm using several svg images within my own application. Later, I'll add a functionality to reduce opacity to all svg elements. While this is a trivial task when using native svg elements, it doesn't appear to be working within image tag.

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/iGAnaVi/1/edit

As you can see, when I applied opacity to group element, text tag was affected, however, image tag was not.
I am aware that .svg file when viewed is nothing but native svg elements. However, I'd still rather reduce opacity to a single image tag. Is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use [opacity](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#OpacityProperty) rather than fill-opacity and/or stroke-opacity

Comment: @ErikDahlström - Yes it does, because `image` is a graphics element: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermGraphicsElement

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straightforwards I've just noticed: 
so, without style and additional attributes, just opacity.